# Jquery Autocomplete move items to new div

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to make a shopping list using autocomplete.  When you hit the add button I would want this to move the item into the shoppinglist but I am getting undefined

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ktcle/pbmL2q1e/1/

```
    <input type="text" id="auto" />
    <button id="click">
    Add to your selection
    </button>

    <button id="add" class="hidden">Item does not exist. Click here to add it.</button>

    <div id="your-selection">
    your shopping list


    </div>
```

and the js

```
    var source = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Grapes", "Bread", "Milk"];

    $(function () {
        $("#auto").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(source, request.term));
                $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                $("#add").toggle(!ui.item);
            }
        });


        $("#click").on("click", function (request) {
           var thehtml = '<strong>Item:</strong> ' + request.source;
            $('#your-selection').html(thehtml);
        });


        $("#add").on("click", function () {
            source.push($("#auto").val());
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: At a time only one item can be added in shopping list. Right?

Comment: no all of them, to create the list, so it keeps populating the below div

Comment: If user select apples and then add it in list then textbox will get empty and user can able to select another item and can add it in list and so on... Am I right?

Comment: yes that is the functionality that I am looking for but am struggling with,  thanks

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get selected item please use `$("#auto").val()`. Please check below code for the same.

```
$("#click").on("click", function () {
    var newSelected = $("#auto").val();
    var thehtml = '<br/>' + $("#auto").val();
    var selectedItems = $('#your-selection').html();
    if(selectedItems.indexOf(newSelected) === -1){
      $('#your-selection').append(thehtml); 
    }else{
      alert("Already selected!");
    }
    $("#auto").val('');
});
```

Please check below snippet for more understanding

```js
var source = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Grapes", "Bread", "Milk"];

$(function () {
  $("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(source, request.term));
      //$('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
      $("#add").toggle(!ui.item);
    }
  });


  $("#click").on("click", function () {
    var newSelected = $("#auto").val();
    var thehtml = '<br/>' + $("#auto").val();
    var selectedItems = $('#your-selection').html();
    if(selectedItems.indexOf(newSelected) === -1){
      $('#your-selection').append(thehtml); 
    }else{
      alert("Already selected!");
    }
    $("#auto").val('');
  });


  $("#add").on("click", function () {
    source.push($("#auto").val());
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }

#your-selection{margin: 1em 0; background: pink; width: 200px; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="auto" />
<button id="click">
  Add to your selection
</button>

<button id="add" class="hidden">Item does not exist. Click here to add it.</button>

<div id="your-selection">
  your shopping list Items
</div>
```